# Send hidden field from current MVC view to the MVC view about to be loaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, hidden-field

When a certain link gets clicked on my _Layout.cshtml page a prompt asks for a value. I store this value in a hidden field in the same view. Now before I finish loading Recommended.cshtml I want to see if the hidden field value matches a constant value I created. Everything works, except I can't figure out how to get the hidden value into the view about to be loaded. Could I maybe use a `[HttpPost] ActionResult` on _Layout.cshtml? What would be best practice in this situation?

Model:

```
[Bind]
public class RecommendedModel
{
    [StringLength(50), Required(ErrorMessage = "This field is required.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    private const string _TOKEN = "pass";
    public string Token { get { return _TOKEN; } }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Recommended(RecommendedModel _recommendedModel)
{
    if (_recommendedModel.Password == _recommendedModel.Token)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Recommended.";
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

View (The hidden field is actually on my shared _Layout page):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Password)
```

JavaScript:

```
var password = prompt("What is the password?", "");
document.getElementById("Password").value = password;
```

EDIT: All of this code works except `_recommendedModel.Password` is null. It should have the string the user entered into the prompt, unless I did not map it correctly.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly your problem is. What do you expect to happen, what does happen? What do you mean by _"I can't figure out how to get the hidden value into the view about to be loaded"_?

Comment: I click a link in my shared _Layout.cshtml file. Then my javascript changes the hiddenfield also in my _Layout.cshtml file to the value the user enters into the prompt. I believe I have this correctly mapped using @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Password). Edit: My problem is how should I access the hiddenfield in public ActionResult Recommended. _recommendedModel.Password is null in my current code.

Comment: Explain, in your question, step by step what you are doing, what you see happening and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, change the ActionResult method to receive the hidden field as a parameter, like this:

```
public ActionResult Recommended(RecommendedModel _recommendedModel, string password)
```

Then, set a ViewBag variable, for example, with that parameter value and put it on your "next" View.

```
ViewBag.password = password;
```

Remember your hidden field must be inside the form element in order to be passed to the controller.

**edit**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerName", "Recommended")) {
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Password)
   <input name="Save" type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about where to put the ViewBag code. If it's a link on my shared _Layout page that prompts the password to get to the next view would I have to do some sort of [HttpPost] on _Layout that inserts the ViewBag key?

Comment: In our question you state `how to get the hidden value into the view about to be loaded`: After the prompt, you store the inserted value (a password) in a hidden field on the same view, right? And then you want to pass that password to the next view, right?

Comment: Ok, in your `ActionResult` method, add a parameter and set the ViewBag variable, as in my answer above. Then, in your next view, simply write `@ViewBag.password` anywhere and it should show the password on that view. (Not sure why you would show a password, but that's none of my business)

Comment: I don't want to show a password. I want to pass it server side so I can check it against a token. The problem is the ActionResult Recommended is where I need to have it passed. I can't set it there. I get the password from a prompt on my master page, _Layout.cshtml. I can't figure out how to do a HttpPost on _Layout or if I even should.

Comment: What if you set it inside the ActionResult? Like `_recommendedModel.Password = password`?

Comment: As in`public ActionResult Recommended(RecommendedModel _recommendedModel, string password)
{ _recommendedModel.Password = password; }` ? `password` is null.

Comment: In the View, is your hidden field inside a form? It will only be passed to the ActionResult if it's inside a form that's submitted. Otherwise, it will be null

Comment: @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post)) {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Password)
    }

Comment: See my edit in the answer. That input will call the `Recommended` method and send the password parameter to it

Answer (score 0):

Your password field should be inside  tag. If it is outside the form tag make sure you will pass the value from that field to the contrller using javascript/jquery